# New AD DCs, Roles transferred, but still dependent on old DCs?

Tags: active-directory

**Background:**

I have 2x DCs running W2k3 as VM on VMWare.

I created 2x DCs running W2k12 (not R2) on HyperV, joined them together under same site & all.

All roles were transferred to the 2 new DCs, updated my DHCP & router to point to the new DCs.

My intention was to slowly kill off the 2 old DCs & VMware as they were running on an old VM infrastructure.

**Setting:**

All DCs have their preferred DNS set to themselves, alternate DNS = 127.0.0.1, and a couple of other DCs added to the additional DNS list.

**Problem:**

A recent power cycle in the building forced me to shutdown every servers. Naturally my DCs were the last to go.

When the power came up the next day, I started the HyperV hosts and new DCs first. All booted fine but I notice the DNS service never came up.

Only when I booted up the old VMware server + old DCs, did the service came alive and all went back to normal.

**Errors:**

Errors in the DNS log = Event 4013, *The DNS server is waiting for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed. The DNS server service cannot start until the initial synchronization is complete because critical DNS data might not yet be replicated onto this domain controller.*

**Question:**

Why is there still a dependency on the old servers? If my old hardware are to fail tomorrow, will my setup fail as well?

Comment: What do the new DC's use for DNS?

Comment: My intention is to slowly de-commission the old DCs. So the new DCs are to replace the functionality of the old DCs.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. What are the new DC's using for DNS? Are they using themselves or are they using the old DC's?

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't catch your qn. Yes, their DNS is set to themselves. Both has static IP defined, and preferred DNS = themselves, alternate DNS = 127.0.0.1. 

Under additional DNS, I've also added each other as well as one of the older DCs

Comment: Demote the old DCs and clean up their AD records. There are articles on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In a single DC environment the DNS config on the card would list itself as Primary DNS and localhost as the secondary. This sounds like what you have now. The Best practices says that if you are going to have 2 DC's then they should point to each other as primary, and point to themselves as secondary. Don't add any other DNS servers to the list, at least for now.
Set your forwarders to your upstream provider's DNS servers, do not use the public ones.

Next you want to look at Replication. Check the logs and make sure there are no repl errors. With clean repl logs, let them set for a while and replicate.
With the 5 FSMO roles moved over, and replication complete, its time to demote the two old DC's, then remove them from the domain.
-larryc

Comment: `The Best practices says that if you are going to have 2 DC's then they should point to each other as primary, and point to themselves as secondary. Don't add any other DNS servers to the list, at least for now` - Your DNS recommendation is spot on, except that the Microsoft BPA for the DNS role recommends adding 127.0.0.1. My recommendation is to add 127.0.0.1 as tertiary on each of the new DC's.